Geometric morphisms for double categories
Is such there a notion 'Geometric morphism' for double categories? I have been reading Jean Benabou's lecture notes on fibred categories. He has slides on fibred geometric morphisms for arbitrary categories. I have been searching for a corresponding notion and I could not find it. This is out of curiosity.
Link to slides: Slides

If you mean simply an adjunction in which the left adjoint preserves finite limits, this definition makes sense immediately for double categories: i.e. the left adjoint should preserve finite products, equalisers, and tabulators. Are you looking for something else?

Yes  @varkor that is what I mean, perhaps my question is whether such adjunctions are well studied or they are pretty easy to think about.

Are there facts in the 1-categorical setting about geometric morphisms you would like to know hold for double categories? I'm not sure what kind of facts you're looking for.

Yes, perhaps even 2-categorical. Maybe thats the simplest.

Could you provide a list of results for 1- or 2-categorical geometric morphisms that you'd like analogues of for double categories? There's no comprehensive study of such things for double categories, but perhaps if you have results in mind, then we can provide references.
